# VS 2015 - Unable to Deploy to Windows Phone 8.1 Device

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I have built a minimal project in VS 2015 targetting Windows Phone 8.1.

This runs fine on the emulator but when I try to deploy to an attached phone, the deployment never finishes.

In the VS status bar it shows "Deploy started..." for about 5 minutes and then it changes to "Ready" but the build/deploy animation (further to the right on the status bar) keeps going.

At this point the app is not visible on the phone and VS is still "busy" doing something - Build and other menu options are greyed out.

Any suggestions on how to diagnose the problem please?

From the same machine I can deploy to the same phone using VS 2013 without a problem.

Update: I tried letting the deployment continue running and after about 10 minutes there was a flurry activity and the deployment completed. No error was displayed but this is obviously very slow.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that patience is the key here. The first deployment was very slow (about 10 minutes) but subsequent deployments were about 20 seconds. So it does work...